# Spring MVC: where should I do input validation?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, validation, spring-mvc

I am using AJAX controller. Here is the workflow:

1. User enters the data in the textbox, hits **search**
2. If the entered data doesn't correspond to the expected (valid) data format (ie some exact regex) - **Validation error message should pop up**
3. If the entered data is correct, the controller is called. Controller calls the external service based on (validated) data from the user (textbox), and returns the corresponding JSON, and AJAX returns in back to client-side Javascript

**Controller.java**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "api/user/{user}", produces = "application/json", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public @ResponseBody UserData execute(@PathVariable(value = "user") String user) {

    if(validator.isValid(user)) {
        return service.getUserData(user);
    } else {
        throw new ResourceNotFoundException(INVALID_USER_FORMAT);
    }
```

**Javascript**

```
// obtain user from text input
var user = $('#user_input').val();

$.getJSON("/api/user/"+user, function (data) {
    // ...
});
```

For now, I have the validation done in my controller, and NOT in Javascript. For example, I could remove it from controller, and just have it in Javascript, like this:

```
    // obtain user from text input
    var user = $('#user_input').val();

    if(validate(asin)) {
           $.getJSON("/api/user/"+user, function (data) {
                // ...
           });
    }
```

**The question**

What is better, and what is more a good pattern? Having validation in Controller like such, or in Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

It is good to have validation on both side but client side validation is must, client side validation will save lot server hit by restricting data with invalid format.

Answer (score 0):

It is always preferred to validate both the side.

Server side validation required for security reason. It is not necessary that user always send request through client UI. some of malicious user can use curl request [ex. postman] and any script for [ex JavaScript, angular etc] for request manipulation.

So always assume that client can send anything you should validate it on server side as well.